# How to stop pipe jq execution based on condition?

Tags: activecampaign

Using ActiveCampain work flows, I have a pipeline in which I want to execute code conditionally based on the output of a jq command.

For example, I want to execute and `!http` and `!jq` command if `.status == "event-created"`.

JSON

```
{
    "id":1,
    "firstname": "Nj",
    "lastname": "Bhanushali",  
    "email": "test@test.com",  
    "title":"Call with new lead",
    "status":"event-created" 
}
```

Code

```
"!pipe": [
    {
        "!jq": ".status"
    },  
    //call this jq if .status == "event-created" 
    {
        "!http": {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/contact/fields"
        }
    },
    {
        "!jq": "${piped_content::1}"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the docs suggest there's a [`!switch`](https://developers.activecampaign.com/docs/commands-1#switch-command-a-nameswitch-commanda) "command" you can use.

```json
{
  "!switch": {
    "jq": "if .status == \"event-created\" then 0 else 1 end",
    "cases": [
      {
        "!pipe": [
          {
            "!http": {
              "method": "GET",
              "path": "/contact/fields"
            }
          },
          {
            "!jq": "${piped_content::1}"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notes:

- I don't know if it's acceptable to have an empty hash for one of the cases. Maybe you have to use `null`? Maybe you have to omit it? If you omit it, maybe you have to use `if .status == "event-created" then 0 else empty end`? If that works, that would be the cleanest solution. Adjust as necessary.
- I don't know if `${piped_content::1}` is still correct with the changes I've made. Adjust as necessary.